# How to compare string vs. list of lists in Python/Spyder 2.7

Tags: python, string, list, comparison, spyder

I have a list:

```
myList = [['first'],['second'], ['third']]
```

and a comparison string, `myStr = 'first'`

I want to return `True` if myStr exists in myList, else `False`.

Comment: I cannot even guess your language. Tag with it if you want to get an aswer sometime...

Answer (score 2):

Just for the simple example you have shown, run

```
[myStr] in myList
```

But you should probably make `myList` equal a flat list if each sublist contains only one item - `myList = ['first', 'second', 'third']`

Then you only need

```
myStr in myList
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.7:

```
str = "first"
array = [["first"], ["second"], ...]
def isInArray(string, array):
    for subarray in array:
        for element in subarray:
            if element == string:
                return True
    return False
print isInArray(str, array)
```

Anyway, the array makes no sense: if each subarray has only one element, you should make it easier:

```
array = ["first", "second", ...]
```

Comment: I agree.  The array was naively generated: with open('csvFileName.csv','rb') as f:   data=list( list( rec ) for rec in csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')).  I am new to this, so please tell me how to read in the csv rows your easier format.  Thank you.

Comment: @BLevy you should ask that as a different question, if there isn't already a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the list with the for loop just once so that you can access the sublists

```
myStr = 'first'
myList = [['first'],['second'], ['third']]

def str_in_list_of_lists(myStr, myList):
    for i in myList:
        if myStr in i:
            return True
    return False
print str_in_list_of_lists(myStr, myList)
```

Example in Python 2.7:

```
food = [["apples", "prunes", "peaches"], ["tea", "coffee", "milk"], ["biscuits", "bread", "chips"]]

*You can try different strings here to check True/False values*

find = raw_input("What do you want in food?")

def str_in_list_of_lists(a, b):
    for i in food:
        if find in i:
            return True
    return False
print str_in_list_of_lists(find, food)
```